# Python Installation for All Users

Tags: python, path, scrapy, multiple-users

I'm running into an issue where if I install Python for myself (admin) only, my application runs just fine... but when I install Python for all users, I get errors such as

`scrapy is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

I'm not sure what is causing this. It seems to be something path related, but I'm not sure how to go about solving that for all users.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: A few links I just checked say that if you modify `PATH`, it should apply to all users.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan that's what I thought as well, I'm just not sure what's going on here

Comment: @Bob do you use anaconda?